# Trouble installing selectize.js in Docker container

Tags: javascript, docker, npm

Deploying a web-app Docker container.

The docker-compose config file adds a temp Composer container, that reads from a ./html/composer.json file.

I have added the `selectize` npm strings for installation as another entry to my `"require"` key/value pair, trying a few different versions:

- "@selectize/selectize": "^0.13.5"
- "selectize/selectize": "^0.13.5"
- "selectize": "^0.13.5"

There are some other repos, so I have also used their lower 0.12.6 version. This also does not work.

When I use the first option, in the temp composer container, the log file is:

> ,
> ,   [RuntimeException]
> ,   require.@selectize/selectize is invalid, it should have a vendor
> name, a forward slash, and a package name. The vendor and package name
> can be words separated by -, . or _. The complete name should match
> "^a-z0-9*/a-z0-9*$".  ,
> , ,

The full composer.json file is:

```
{
    "require": {
        "mongodb/mongodb": "^1.8.0",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^5.3.0",
        "auth0/auth0-php": "^7.9.0",
        "@selectize/selectize": "^0.13.5"
    },
    "provide" : {
        "ext-mongodb": "*"
    }
}
```

Comment: The first one ("@selectize/selectize": "^0.13.5") looks right package to install, what type of error do you get?

Comment: Update main post with log file

Comment: You have just some typo, can you post the whole composer.json or just require section.

Comment: Added the composer.json file into the main post

Comment: The package name is ok, but that is npm package, not a composer package. If you want a package manager for npm, create one with "npm init" and use it (new package.json) for install package (like npm install @selectize/selectize).

Comment: Feel such a fool! Is it the same concept as this `composer` approach? i.e. 1 container that puts the filesystem / library in place, then a 2nd container can use that code. Or different? Any recommended material / search criteria for info & tutorials? Tried a few but nothing that fills in many gaps for me so far...

Comment: I'm not sure what you want, maybe at some point you just want install nodejs (`RUN apt-get install nodejs -y`) and run `RUN npm install` at build stage (ie after composer install step). You do not need a second container if you did not run some node/js app